# correct sense of the word "ubiquitous"

Tags: word-usage

I want to say that railways is most commonly used form of transport in the country.
Am I using the word "ubiquitous" correctly to convey the meaning?

> City X is not accessible directly by rail (which is ***ubiquitous in the country*** / ***most commonly used mode of long distance transport in the country***) and is known for its extreme climate.

Comment: Literally, *ubiquitous* means *everywhere*. So if some city is not accessible directly by rail, saying that rail is *ubiquitous* is a contradiction.

Comment: Nonsense, @PeterShor. _Everywhere_ is one of the meanings of _ubiquitous_, but not the only one.

Comment: @Colin: that's why I said "literally". It comes from the Latin word *ubique*, meaning *everywhere*. And the meaning *widespread* is a metaphorical extension of the meaning *everywhere*. (Similarly, *everywhere* can also mean *widespread*.)

Comment: And I would say that that is an example of the Etymological fallacy, @PeterShor. What a word comes from tells you nothing reliable about its meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ubiquitous* simply means “common”, not necessarily “most common”.

Therefore, if you want to convey that people won’t have any trouble finding a train to catch, than *ubiquitous* would work just fine.

On the other hand, if you want to say that people travel by train more than by any other transport, then you should use *most common*.